# OLED 128x64 bitmap display issue [ARDUINO]

Tags: c, bitmap, arduino

I am using the following display : https://www.adafruit.com/products/938

I ran the code they have on git and it works perfectly, I can see all their tests and all it's fine however the moment I add my own bitmap(via LCD assistant) as follows :

```
const unsigned char tedst [] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xE0, 0xE0, 0xE0, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x7C,
0x7C, 0x3C, 0x3E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xFE,
0xDE, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,
0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE0, 0xF8, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8F, 0x87, 0x87, 0x07,
0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x87, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFC, 0x78, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0xC0, 0xC0,
0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x81, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE0, 0xC0, 0x80,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC7, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F,
0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFC, 0xFE, 0x3F, 0x1F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x07,
0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xE0,
0xE0, 0xE0, 0xE0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE0,
0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x1F, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
0xFF, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x3F, 0x7E, 0xF8,
0xF8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xF8, 0x7C, 0x3E, 0x3F, 0x1F, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x80, 0xE0, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x07, 0x07,
0x03, 0x83, 0xC3, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x0F,
0x0F, 0x1F, 0x1E, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x3E, 0x1F, 0x1F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x03,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F,
0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F,
0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

I then follow up with :

```
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.drawBitmap(0, 0,  tedst, 128, 64, 1);
  display.display();
```

As the image is as big as the screen and when I do so the screen flickers with half of your logo(the first image, I did not alter the loop so all animations will be there) and random artifacts. The moment I delete my 3 lines, it is all back to normal, ideas why please?

Answer (score 0):

use dot factory at http://www.pavius.net/wp-content/uploads/the-dot-factory/versions/TheDotFactory-0.1.4.7z where you set the output as binary, the thing works perfectly